# Same post requests different responses?

Tags: .net

Im developing a small app that authenticates a user against my friends website and lets them do several things once there logged in, If i send the post request using hurl.it I get a 302 moved temporarily which is what I want because it means the user credentials are correct but when I send a post request in vb.net I get a 200 okay despite using the exact same credentials and parameters ?

```
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("")
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim postData As String = ""
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim responseData As String = response.Headers.Get("Location")
    Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()
```

What im asking is why does hurl.it provide the 302 response i want to achieve but my .NET post request gets a 200 OK response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302 302 is used for redirection, i.e. a browser would automatically move on to the url pointed to by the 302.  The  HttpWebRequest class does the same by default.

However it can be configured, see here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

I would expect that setting `AllowAutoRedirect=False` will provide your expected behaviour.

to quote https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect(v=vs.110).aspx:

> true if the request should automatically follow redirection responses
>   from the Internet resource; otherwise, false. The default value is
>   true.... If AllowAutoRedirect is set to false, all responses with an
>   HTTP status code from 300 to 399 is returned to the application.

Comment: That worked great thanks! Never knew AllowAutoRedirect existed!